# modulo to cycle though a compute buffer not working as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

**The Setup**
In my compute-shader I have a `StructuredBuffer` that is storing an amount of colors. There is also an int variable storing the amount of colors in total ( `_colres` ). From another script a node tree is dispatched into the shader every frame. The amount of nodes changes dynamically. Because of that the points buffer containing the nodes is at a fixed size of 8192 that the amount of nodes never exceeds.

**The Problem**
When I'm now trying to draw the points I am storing in the points buffer, oddly enough only every third color is displayed, starting at index [0] (tested for up to 12 colors -> [0],[3],[6],[9]).

```
Result[pointsBuffer[id.x].xy] = colorsBuffer[id.x % _colres];
```

**What I tried**
I used the `fmod()` function instead but was presented with the same result. Individually targeting stored colors by hard-coding the index has worked so my guess would be that the colors buffer is not the problem. Maybe it has something to do with all the empty spaces in the pointsbuffer but I could't figure it out.

**The Question(s)**
Is there a fundamental problem I am overlooking?
Is there some other simple way to cycle through the indices of my colorsbuffer that works in this scenario?

**Detailed Information**
System:
Unity Version **2021.2.12f1** using the **HDRP** on **MacOS Monterey 12.2.1**
Compute-Shader

```
#pragma kernel DrawPoints

// texture
shared RWTexture2D<float4> Result;
int _texres;
int _colres;

// buffer
StructuredBuffer<float2> pointsBuffer;
StructuredBuffer<float4> colorsBuffer;

[numthreads(64,1,1)]
void DrawPoints (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if ((pointsBuffer[id.x].x * pointsBuffer[id.x].y) > 0) Result[pointsBuffer[id.x].xy] = colorsBuffer[id.x % _colres];
}
```

C# Setup

```
public differentialGrowth diffGrowth;

int texResolution = 4096;
int colorAmount = 12;

RenderTexture settingRef;
Material target;
ComputeShader shader;

RenderTexture outputTexture;
ComputeBuffer pointsBuffer;
ComputeBuffer colorsBuffer;

int pointsHandle;



 void Start()
    {
        outputTexture = new RenderTexture(settingRef);
        outputTexture.enableRandomWrite = true;
        outputTexture.Create();

        // INIT

        pointsHandle = shader.FindKernel("DrawPoints");

        shader.SetInt("_texres", texResolution);
        shader.SetInt("_colres", colorAmount);

        int stride = (3) * 4; // every component as a float (3) * 4 bytes per float
        pointsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(8192, stride);

        stride = (4) * 4;
        colorsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(colorAmount, stride);
        
        shader.SetTexture( pointsHandle, "Result", outputTexture );

        target.SetTexture("_MainTex", outputTexture);

Color[] testColors = new Color[colorAmount];
        testColors[0] = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0); //red _ yes
        testColors[1] = new Color(0, 1, 0, 0); //green
        testColors[2] = new Color(0, 0, 1, 0); //blue
        testColors[3] = new Color(1, 1, 0, 0); //yellow _yes
        testColors[4] = new Color(0, 1, 1, 0); //cyan
        testColors[5] = new Color(1, 0, 1, 0); //magenta
        testColors[6] = new Color(0.5f, 0, 1, 0); //mix6 _yes
        testColors[7] = new Color(1, 0.5f, 1, 0); //mix7
        testColors[8] = new Color(0.5f, 0, 1, 0); //mix8
        testColors[9] = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0); //mix9 _yes
        testColors[10] = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0); //mix10
        testColors[11] = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0); //mix11
    }

    void Update()
    {
        pointsBuffer.SetData(diffGrowth.nodes.Points);
        shader.SetBuffer(pointsHandle, "colorsBuffer", colorsBuffer);
        shader.SetBuffer(pointsHandle, "pointsBuffer", pointsBuffer);
        shader.Dispatch(pointsHandle, 128, 1, 1);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (pointsBuffer != null) pointsBuffer.Dispose();
        if (colorsBuffer != null) colorsBuffer.Dispose();
    }
}
```